# How to simple authorized user using @PreAuhorized annotation

Tags: java, spring-security

In my app I want to only protect method so I created this simple security context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    </http>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />


</beans:beans>
```

In my service I have method login which is called when login form is submited but I have no idea what should be there please help:

```
public ExtDirectFormPostResult login(Person person, BindingResult result) {
    ExtDirectFormPostResult postResult = new ExtDirectFormPostResult(result);
    logger.error("logiiiiiiiiin ");
    // what to do to allow   using annotatedmethod  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")?   
    return postResult;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give more details. How are you logging in? Your configuration doesn't include any Spring Security authentication functionality. What do you actually want to protect?